# Building error R Math in Julia

Tags: windows, julia

When I want to use the GLM Package on Windows I get the problem

```
Rmath not properly installed. Please run Pkg.build("Rmath") and restart Julia.
```

But then the following error occurs:

```
Failed to precompile Rmath to ...
```

which then produces the error notification

> Exception by Determining of "SecurityProtocol": "NULL can not
>   converted to the type "System.Net.SecurityProtocolType" because it is
>   not a possible value for enumerations values. Enter a possible value
>   "Ss13, Tls"

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried running what the error message says: `Pkg.build("Rmath")`?

Comment: yes. Changed nothing. Just downloading the zip and then building it, worked ... totally strange!

Comment: Maybe you had a build error, or a dependency missing. Rebuilding the package sometimes helps, that's why GLM suggested that. :)

Comment: @Hamlet How did you build the package after you'd downloaded the zip?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out: the 'dll' needs to be placed into the 'bin' folder of the Julia installation. Then simply running 'Pkg.build("Rmath")' works.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than an actual solution to the issue.

The problem is likely a networking one (e.g., running Julia from behind a proxy server). The way to solve it is to manually download the 'zip' file whose address is given in the error when the build fails, unpack it into the 'bin' folder of Julia installation (typically something like 'C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\[julia version]\bin'), and then run
`Pkg.build("Rmath")` in Julia.